# Filter by category and city for doctors and hospitals in wordpress

Tags: filters

I'm working on wordpress medical website which shows all the doctors and hospitals. I'm confused that doctors and hospitals will come as a page or product. I also want to add filter by category (like for doctors - cardiac surgeon, plastic surgeon etc AND for hospitals like cardiac hospitals, plastic surgery hospitals etc) and filter by city. How should I start working on this.

Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should register two custom post types:

1. Doctor
2. Hospital

using function [register_post_type()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/)

and then register two custom taxonomies added to both custom posts we registered above

1. Specialty (cardiac, plastic)
2. City

using function [register_taxonomy()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/)

In my opinion this is a good way to move forward

Comment: Can you refer any link. I'm completely new to wp hence not really understanding some things. May be if I get good documentation that will help. Thanks

Comment: Hey , I have put two links above already